# Unity bouncing ball with scripts

Tags: unity-game-engine, gravity

how do I create a bouncing ball in unity that bounces to the same height and that I can make it fall quicker or slower? I've tried to do it from rigid body settings but the ball keeps climbing and I can't control the falling speed. Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiply your desired height vector with a positive sine wave (negative values get multiplied by -1) and add this to your initial position of the ball.

To control the speed of the ball you can multiply the value you use to evaluate the sine function with another factor.

```
heightVector * |sin(time * speed)|
```

[image]

Comment: I'm new in unity 3d, where do i insert this ? heightVector * |sin(time * speed)|

Comment: This is the mathematical formula to calculate the position of the ball, if it starts from 0. Add it to your start position to get the relative position.

Comment: My ball starts at y =50, should i create a script and add "heightVector * |sin(time * speed)|" it?

Comment: `transform.position` is your ball's current position, add the calculated vector that you get from the formula to this one.